# (Using Spring, MVC, Java, MYSQL) How do I let the user create a new table in the MYSQL database through the UI?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I'm using JSP files for some of the pages in my application.  I know how to let them enter data (CRUD as well) into a table I created for the user.

But, I'd like to know what I need to do in the JSP code and in the backend Java code so that a user can create a table in the database through the UI, where they get to name the table and the columns of it.

How do I do this? It's not like the user can write the code for the Controller and Class (class that includes object variables) when making a table. So what to do ?

I'm using Spring and am using MVC. Writing it in Java. Database is MYSQL.

Or do I simply have to directly write out the DDL commands in Java to make this happen, and can't do this in the MVC pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest (and discouraged) way:

1. text-field *sql* in jsp
2. model with String *sql* that is mapped to the field above
3. controller with something like

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(Model model) {
    jdbcTemplate.execute(model.getSql());
}
```

4. jsp directs form to */submit* url
5. as user write full SQL to the field

The controller code is taken from memory so for full version please google-search.

As upgrade divide pieces of SQL to text-fields so the user would not have to enter full SQL query by themselves but only column/table names.

Sanitization of the *sql* field is required.

I would discourage such an approach but it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost on 1, 2, and 5. could you elaborate some more? or point me to a link with example code?  I'm struggling to find code examples so that's why I'm on here.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/avansinformatica/spring-mvc-library (first i found). It uses thymeleaf so the view would be different.

Comment: Or https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Comment: There is an even better example: https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example

Comment: the last one helped me immensely. basically the reason i figured it all out. thank you.